# Maintain NodeJS Server on ec2 Instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-serverless

I have an issue and I am not sure how to create this one on AWS ec2. So I have a File (server.js) that runs a NodeJS (Express) Server. It is pretty straight forward.

My Idea is:

Create a custom Image with the NodeJS Server and use this Image (AMI) for my Auto Scaling Group. This works, but has a big downside. If I need to maintain the server.js File, I need to create a new Image and Maintain the server.js, this is somehow a downside.

So what would be for you best practice to (best case)

I have in Github a Repo with a server.js
After making a change, I want to deploy this server.js to all running ec2 Instances or replace them. But the traffic is really high (billions of invokes per month), so I need to avoid downtimes.

Any recommandations are welcome

Comment: Use a blue-green deployment strategy
With a blue-green deployment, you have two identical environments, one "blue" and one "green". The blue environment is the production environment that is currently serving traffic, while the green environment is a staging environment that is not yet serving traffic.
It allows you to deploy updates to your Node.js server without experiencing any downtime, as traffic is seamlessly redirected from the blue environment to the green environment.

You can automate this process by using tools like AWS CodePipeline or Jenkins to automate the deployment process.

Comment: you can use github actions or CodePipeline to automate the deployment.